# Div width not changing using Bootstrap and jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="form">
<p class="pull-right"><a href="#" class="toggle-form"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" id="toggle-icon"></i></a></p>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="contact-form">
    <h3><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact Us</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Full Name *" required />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number *" required />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <span class="pull-right"><small>* indicates required field</small></span>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.toggle-form').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#toggle-icon').toggleClass('fa-minus-square fa-plus-square');
    var toggleWidth = $(".form").width() == 400 ? "50px" : "400px";
    $('.form').animate({ width: toggleWidth });
    $('#contact-form').fadeToggle();
});
});
```

See this [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/keithmclaughlin/vztyfLz3/3/).

I have the form over a Google Map and want to be able to minimize the form so people can view the map. When the user clicks the minus icon I want the div to reduce to the width of only the icon.

It seems that Bootstrap (v3.3.1) is stopping the width from reducing down. If I exclude the Bootstrap css file it works as expected. I think it might be something to do with box-sizing, but have no idea how to fix it.

Any advice is very much appreciated.

Comment: Even though you have specified `width:400px;` its not equal to that value initially. I'm getting 360px. You should use a conditional statement instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the form's width doesn't match the condition. Try changing it to:

```
$(".form").width() > 50 ? "50px" : "400px";
```